# Heroku task over 24h

Tags: heroku, background-process

I have a task that runs over 24h, and gets restarted by heroku - as it restarts tasks daily:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-dyno-manifold

Leaving the length of the task, and what it is aside - is it possible to leave it so that it runs to completion ? Or would I have to figure out how to save state of the task ?

Comment: I would definitely break up the task into many smaller tasks, and work out a way to save the state.

Look into a system such as Celery (Python) or Resque (Ruby), or whatever best suits the language that you are using.

From there you should be able to work out a way to put the tasks into a queue, and process them. Furthermore, you will also have the ability to scale easily using Background Dynos. This should be the way that you handle large tasks such as this, especially if your current task is taking over 24 hours to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to figure out how to save the state of your process. Heroku does not provide a way for you to make a dyno run longer then 24 hours.

That aside, it may be in your best interest to delocalize the state anyways, doing so will help you with scalability, help the process be more resilient, and work on heroku. You may be interested in checking out [this document](http://www.12factor.net/) for some best practices on heroku